# How many times has Abeloth escaped?

Tags: star-wars

I have just finished reading [Fate of the Jedi: Apocalypse](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Apocalypse). I remember the part where the Jedi team reviewed the Killik's art and learned of [Abeloth, the Bringer of Chaos](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Abeloth). Apparently the art revealed that she escaped several times before 43 BBY.

When were those times? Does anyone have specifics, is there any sources outside of the scant details from the novel?

Comment: Why the downvotes? Seems like a reasonable question to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abeloth is a new figure in the EU.  I have not seen anything outside of the the [Fate of the Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Fate_of_the_Jedi) series that has referenced her.  What we know right now we know from the novels based on the Klikliks renderings.  From that it seems that it has happened more than once.  But how many times is not something that matters to the Klikliks so we have no knowledge of how many.  It seems that the Klikliks are the only survivors we know of that have a history that includes the bringer of Chaos.